limit of root function without using hopital
Hi everyone i want to prove without using hopital that :
$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2\sqrt{1+x^4\sqrt{1+x^8\sqrt{1+x^{16}}}}}-\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{1+x^6\sqrt{1+x^{12}}}}}\right)=+\infty$

here is my approach :
let $h$ be the function from $\mathbb{R^{+}}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by : $h(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2\sqrt{1+x^4\sqrt{1+x^8\sqrt{1+x^{16}}}}}-\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{1+x^6\sqrt{1+x^{12}}}}} $
if we factorise by : $x^{4}$:
$h(x)=x^{4}\times \left( \sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^4}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^8}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{16}}{x^{16}}}}}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^3}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^6}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{12}}{x^{16}}}}}}\right) $

and we have :
$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^4}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^8}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{16}}{x^{16}}}}}}=1$

and :

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^3}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^6}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{12}}{x^{16}}}}}}=0$

so :

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^4}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^8}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{16}}{x^{16}}}}}}-\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^3}{x^4}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^6}{x^8}\sqrt{\frac{1+x^{12}}{x^{16}}}}}}=1$

and we have :

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\;x^4=+\infty$

therefore :

$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\;h(x)=+\infty$

is my approach correct and thanks everyone

Your factorization by $x^4$ is wrong. For instance, $$\sqrt{1+x^2\sqrt{1+x^4\sqrt{1+x^8\sqrt{1+x^{16}}}}}$$ is not equal to $$\sqrt{(1+x^2)\sqrt{(1+x^4)\sqrt{(1+x^8)\sqrt{1+x^{16}}}}}.$$

thank you you're right

Ok. Here is a completely
elementary and rigorous proof.
Looking at the two parts,
$\begin{array}\\
t1
&=\sqrt{1+x^2\sqrt{1+x^4\sqrt{1+x^8\sqrt{1+x^{16}}}}}\\
&>\sqrt{x^2\sqrt{x^4\sqrt{x^8\sqrt{x^{16}}}}}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2\sqrt{x^4\sqrt{x^{16}}}}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2\sqrt{x^{12}}}\\
&=\sqrt{x^8}\\
&=x^4\\
\end{array}
$
and
$\begin{array}\\
t2
&=\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{1+x^6\sqrt{1+x^{12}}}}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{1+x^6\sqrt{4x^{12}}}}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{1+x^62x^6}}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^3\sqrt{4x^{12}}}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+x^32x^6}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x\sqrt{4x^9}}\\
&<\sqrt{1+x2x^{9/2}}\\
&<\sqrt{4x^{11/2}}\\
&=2x^{11/4}\\
\end{array}
$
So
$t1-t2
\gt x^4-2x^{11/4}
=x^{11/4}(x^{5/4}-2)
\to \infty
$.
